# JSON string replace - loop object or string replace?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON string which requires some replacement.

```
{
    "hall1": {
        "contents": {
            "b_pen": "2",
            "r_pen": "4",
            "n_books": "5",
            "f_books": "11"
        },
        "status": "closed"
    },
    "hall2": {
        "contents": {
            "r_pen": "4",
            "b_pen": "1",
            "f_books": "5",
            "n_books": "21"
        },
        "status": "open"
    }
}
```

See the above sample json. I have to replace the keys `b_pen`,`r_pen`, `f_books` and `n_books` to `blue_pen`,`red_pen`, `fictional_books` and `novel_books` respectively. A simple string replace would solve the issue. But this is just a dummy json. Actual JSON has a more length and depth. I am concerned about the performance issues.

Inorder to do this I have two options.

1. Global string replace the JSON string
2. Loop the JSON object and replace the keys

I cannot choose one from this as I am confused.

Comment: Can you share your attempts at this? We can help, but we can't do it for you

Comment: Don't work directly on strings, you may replace unwanted elements. `"foo": "b_pen"`

Comment: replacing the keys is much safer than string replacement.

Comment: @Cid Is there any perfrormance issue while looping and resetting the key ?

Comment: @marzelin I too find that better. But I am confused about performance issues. Is it better than string replacements in performance ?

Comment: @CanO'Spam I am not asking for anyone to do code for me. I have already implemented the string replace method. But I am confused about the performance issues. That's why I thought to ask for the best people about this.

Comment: pre optimisation is the root of evil. First measure if there's really a problem, then optimize. I don't think there's much difference in both approaches. As always, it depends on implementation.

Comment: @Shadow benchmark it and tell us.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out. The logic is to maintain a keymap. Then assign the replacing key with the existing value then delete the old key.

```js
const data={hall1:{contents:{b_pen:"2",r_pen:"4",n_books:"5",f_books:"11"},status:"closed"},hall2:{contents:{r_pen:"4",b_pen:"1",f_books:"5",n_books:"21"},status:"open"}};

const keymap = {b_pen: 'blue_pen', r_pen: 'red_pen', f_books: 'functional_books', n_books: 'novel_books'};

const res = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => {
    if (value?.contents) {
        for (k in value.contents) {
          const x = keymap[k];
          delete Object.assign(value.contents, {[x]: value.contents[k]})[k];
        }
    }
    return [key, value];
  })
);

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```

Comment: I already have the approach with me. I need to find which one is better.

Comment: I think iterating through an object is much efficient than finding and replacing a string.

Answer (score 0):

you have multiple options to do that.
you can use regex or loop through it and replace but the easiest way to do that could be using split and join

here is an example from a similar problem has been answered before

```js
var json = [{"_id":"5078c3a803ff4197dc81fbfb","email":"user1@gmail.com","image":"some_image_url","name":"Name 1"},{"_id":"5078c3a803ff4197dc81fbfc","email":"user2@gmail.com","image":"some_image_url","name":"Name 2"}];
    
json = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json).split('"_id":').join('"id":'));

document.write(JSON.stringify(json));
```